# How to access the child nodes within a parent node

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve data from a webpage forum however they do not have proper classes within their tags which I'm having trouble trying to get from. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rvh7.png)

I've managed to retrieve the other results but the last one; I'm not sure how to extract it. I've tried following a few solutions given by others; etc `container.div.a` but it accesses the first one only, I'm not sure how to get the other one; using a css selector?

this is the the url [link](https://forum.lowyat.net/ReviewsandGuides)

```
try:
    for container in _url.find_all('td', {'class': 'row1', 'valign': 'middle'}):
        topic = container.select_one(
            'a[href^="/topic/]"').text.replace("\n", "")
        description = container.select_one(
            'div.desc').text.replace("\n", "")
        #review_or_guide is what im trying to edit
        review_or_guide = container.find('a', href=True, {'style': 'float:right'}).text
        if topic and description is not None:
            #appends data to list
        else:
            None
except Exception as e:
    print('Error.extractDataFromRow1:', e)
    return None
```

So I'm trying to achieve

```
Topic: Greetings
Description: Hi how are you
Status: Guide
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
review_or_guide = container.select_one("a:nth-of-type(2)").text.strip()
```

This should select the second element within them.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can loop over the table row selector #forum_topic_list > table > tbody > tr and inside the loop you can select td:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(2) > a
in jQuery
Or In css #forum_topic_list > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(2) > a to select all data